# Matched DiD - Should we match at the baseline and hold matching constant?

Tags: matching, difference-in-difference

I have panel data (both ex-ante and post-ante data) and want to examine the effect of a policy change on my treatment group relative to the control group through a matched DiD test using propensity scores.

How should the matching be conducted when you do a DiD? Should you match control and treatment at the baseline and then hold the matching fixed throughout the experiment?
My concern is that ordinary PSM-tools in stata like psmatch2 might match treatment individuals ex-ante with control individuals ex-post.

Dataset: I have panel data with a time series of 3 years before the event (t=0) and 3 years after (t=1).

Do you have any suggestions on how to conduct this experiment?

Many thanks!

Comment: I would suggest not to match using Propensity Scores; use Mahalanobis distances, it is closer to a full-blocked design. See the lecture [here](http://www.methods-colloquium.com/single-post/2015/09/11/Gary-King-Why-Propensity-Scores-Should-Not-Be-Used-for-Matching) and the accompanying presentation. Also I would suggest first formulating what you want to measure and then picking the appropriate methodology rather than forcing a particular methodology to your research question.